# How to fix DbUpdateConcurrencyException when removing multiple entries?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I receive this error when trying to remove entries from the table with EFC

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 30 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.
```

This is my code:

https://paste.mod.gg/xlynuworjmmf/0

```
using MySqlConnector;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal;
using MySql.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Flanium_Agent
{
public class AgentContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Agent> agent { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AgentRequest> agentRequest { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseMySQL("Server=localhost;User ID=root;Database=orchestration_db");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Agent>().HasKey(a => a.Station);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Agent>().ToTable("agents");
        modelBuilder.Entity<AgentRequest>().HasKey(a => a.Station);
        modelBuilder.Entity<AgentRequest>().ToTable("agent_requests");
    }
}

public class Agent
{
    public string Station { get; set; }
    public string Process { get; set; }
    public string Actions { get; set; }
    public string Started { get; set; }
    public string Finished { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}

public class AgentRequest
{
    public string Station { get; set; }
    public string Request { get; set; }
}

public class Agency : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
    private bool ProcessRunning = false;
    private List<string> RequestList = new List<string>();
    public string Station { get; set; }
    public string Process { get; set; }
    public string Actions { get; set; }
    public string Started { get; set; }
    public string Finished { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Request { get; set; }
    
    private Grid DisplayGrid { get; set; }
    private Window appWindow { get; set; }

    public Grid GetDisplayGrid()
    {
        return DisplayGrid;
    }

    public Agency InsertAgentToGrid(Window mainWindow)
    {
        DisplayGrid = new Grid();

        var headerRowDefinition = new RowDefinition();
        headerRowDefinition.Height = new GridLength(50);
        DisplayGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(headerRowDefinition);

        for (var index = 0; index < GetType().GetProperties().Length; index++)
        {
            var property = GetType().GetProperties()[index];
            var header = new TextBlock();
            var column = new ColumnDefinition();
            header.Text = property.Name;
            header.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            header.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            header.FontSize = 16;
            header.FontWeight = FontWeights.Medium;
            Grid.SetRow(header, 0);
            Grid.SetColumn(header, index);

            DisplayGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column);
            DisplayGrid.Children.Add(header);
        }

        var contentRowDefinition = new RowDefinition();
        contentRowDefinition.Height = GridLength.Auto;
        DisplayGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(contentRowDefinition);

        for (var index = 0; index < GetType().GetProperties().Length; index++)
        {
            var propertyValue = GetType().GetProperties()[index];
            var content = new TextBlock();

            content.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            content.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            content.FontSize = 12;
            content.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
            Grid.SetRow(content, 1);
            Grid.SetColumn(content, index);
            DisplayGrid.Children.Add(content);

            var myBinding = new Binding(propertyValue.Name)
            {
                Source = this,
                Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
                UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
            };
            content.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, myBinding);
        }

        DisplayGrid.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        DisplayGrid.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        DisplayGrid.Margin = new Thickness(0, 25, 0, 0);
        (mainWindow.Content as Grid).Children.Add(DisplayGrid);
        appWindow = mainWindow;


        return this;
    }


    private string[] GetPackages()
    {
        var packagesArray = new List<string>();

        var desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        var pathString = Path.Combine(desktopPath, "Flanium Agent Data");
        var packageFolders = Directory.GetDirectories(pathString);
        foreach (var packFolder in packageFolders)
        {
            var versions = Directory.GetDirectories(packFolder);
            if (versions.Length != 0)
            {
                packagesArray.AddRange(versions.Select(version => version.Split('\\').Last())
                    .Select(versionName => packFolder.Split('\\').Last() + "\\" + versionName));
                packagesArray = packagesArray.Select(x => x = pathString + "\\" + x).ToList();
            }
        }

        return packagesArray.ToArray();
    }

    public Agency(string station, string process, string actions, string started, string finished, string status)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var context = new AgentContext())
            {
                context.agent.Add(new Agent
                    {Station = station, Process = process, Actions = actions, Started = started, Finished = finished, Status = status});
                // Saves changes
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            
            Station = station;
            Process = process;
            Actions = actions;
            Started = started;
            Finished = finished;
            Status = status;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            
        }
    }

    public void RemoveAgent()
    {
        using (var context = new AgentContext())
        {
            context.agent.Where(x=> x.Station == Station).ToList().ForEach(x=> context.agent.Remove(x));
            // Saves changes
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        
    }
}
}
```

I followed a tutorial on the internet on how to use EFC by the teeth and for some euclidean reason, as always, the code works for others and the same code does not work when I try it out.

Comment: Are you calling method twice?  When entity does a Query the c# classes are updated and a link is created between the database and the c# classes.  Error indicates that the link was broken in your code.  The error says 30 rows changed instead of 1 row.  So what I think happened is the connection to the database completed and a query was performed.  Then your code started to configure the database a second time. I suspect that when app is started the database is automatically connected and you do not have to do a second time.

Comment: `SaveChanges` persists all pending changes. It's *not* meant to be called after every single change and definitely not inside the constructors of DTOs, much less view model objects. Right now you injected data layer code inside your UI classes

Comment: @jdweng It's only being called once, when my application is opened, it is registed in the SQL Table, when it's closed, it removes itself from the SQL Table, these two events only happen once.

Comment: This code is bad. If it came from a tutorial, the tutorial is *very* bad. Every time this Agency .... window is displayed it creates a *new* `Agent` with a hard-coded name. If there's no PK in the table, opening this 30 times will create 30 records. When `Remove` is called, this will result in 30 deletions when the code told EF that only one would happen.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos there's another logic written in the MainWindow, whenever the application is opened, the Agency Class is created in the SQL table, when the application window is closed, the Agency Class is removed/deleted from the SQL table. These only happen once and in specific events (open/close). But I don't think that code is relevant as this is isolated to this specific class and way of working I wrote.. I think EFC can't work without a primary key after all..

Comment: @LaurianAvrigeanu `Agency` *is* your Window. If it accepts a `Window` parameter it *is* a UI class. That's not what caused this error though, it's just one more serious problem *in this code*. `I think EFC can't work without a primary key after all` No, it's the table that's missing a PK. That's a database problem. That's not EF's fault

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos this is the mainWindow logic: https://paste.mod.gg/yvnoaidmxeii/0

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Agent>().HasKey(a => a.Station);
```

So you have an entity Agent, about which you tell Entity Framework that it has a primary key column named "station".

You have a database with at least 30 records in it, and at least 30 of those records have the same value for the `station` column.

So despite you telling EF that `station` is the primary key, it isn't. So EF generates the query:

```
DELETE FROM agent WHERE station=@station
```

And the database engine happily removes all 30 records for which the station equals the station of the first record it encounters, and reports this, then EF throws, because it expected one record to be deleted, not 30.

The solution: configure the actual primary key as key, or if there isn't any, create one.

Comment: Writing to the database in the constructor is a very bad idea too. Especially the constructor of a viewmodel

Comment: I would like to configure no primary key, and leave it without any, is there no way?

Comment: @LaurianAvrigeanu what are you trying to do? The code you've written mixes up incompatible classes, data and UI components. It's the opposite of layer separation.

Comment: @Laurian theoretically you can, but practically, with Entity Framework, you need a primary key. Especially if you want to delete records. Not having a PK is madness in relational databases.

Comment: The annoying thing with setting a key is that entries are added and removed constantly, so the primaryKey set with AutoIncrement always gets lost in transition, e.g. it was once 1, but the key was removed and it needs to be reset to 1 again since if you remove and add again it just starts from where it finished.

Comment: @Laurian no, you don't need to reset autonumbered keys, that's their whole purpose. If you do, you probably need to redesign something. You actually do need to anyway, see Panagiotis' comment.

Comment: How can I rewrite the logic when this is what it's supposed to be like? The application I made has to run on different stations, when it's opened it needs to register itself in the SQL table, then when it is closed it needs to remove itself from the SQL table. It's impossible to avoid badly numbered keys.

Comment: @LaurianAvrigeanu you need to rewrite everything, including the table. The only way I can think that deleting by a "key" would result in 30 deletions is for 30 duplicates to exist in the table. Which means the table has no real primary key. The code is simply bad - `Agency` is trying to be both a WPF Window, a data binding provider *and* a data layer. That `catch{}` means you encountered problems before and tried to silence them

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you are correct in the assumption that there are duplicates in the table, THERE are duplicates in the table and I want to remove them from the table, I wanted to test mass data removal from an SQL Table.

Comment: @Laurian you should not care about an auto-incrementing primary key's number. Who cares if a station first has ID 1 and later ID 42? If a station's name is supposed to be unique, then it can be a primary key. If you have 30 records with the same value for station, it is by definition not a primary key, as it's not unique.

Comment: @CodeCaster I understand, so the error is happening because I am trying delete all entries by filtering a PRIMARY KEY...? so if I chose any other column to filter by, let's say a Status column, and chose to delete all of the rows that have "In Progress" I wouldn't get this error?

Comment: @LaurianAvrigeanu clean the table with SQL then, add a primary key and *don't* try to cover up duplicate key exceptions. The code is lying to EF, telling it that a PK exists. `HasKey(a=>a.Station)` is telling EF there's only one row per station name. When EF sees that the supposedly unique operation caused 30 modifications, it throws the expected exception

Comment: @Laurian as I said in my answer, you're telling Entity Framework that "status" is your table's primary key. If you have multiple records with the same value for "status", it's by definition not a primary key. Entity Framework can't delete records consistently if you don't define a primary key.